# Is it possible to have a Service node in Python and the Client node in C++?

Tags: python, c++, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the rosserial library, in order to communicate my PC and an Arduino Mega 2560.
As rosserial for PC is only available in Python and I already have an entire code in C++, that's the reason of my question.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199977/is-it-possible-to-have-a-service-node-in-python-and-the-client-node-in-c++?/) by [mutzechai](https://answers.ros.org/users/21222/mutzechai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2014-12-25**:
Congrats on 20,000th question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.
ROS is a multi-lingual OS, the service-client specification is at the messaging layer. P2P communication occurs in XML-RPC. So you can just write your code in any language supported and let the mid-layer handle this for you.
You can take a look at the original paper:
http://www.willowgarage.com/papers/ros-open-source-robot-operating-system

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [wchar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15436/wchar/) with karma: 61 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2